# Is there an advantage to using a csv versus text file when making an embedding for a pretrained LLM?

Tags: large-language-model, openaiembeddings

I’m going to create an embedding for a corpus of information. I’m the example below, is there an advantage to using a CSV versus text file?
CSV:

```
Address,Square footage
333 Rodent st,50000
128 Cat St.,20000
```

Text file:

```
Address: 333 Rodent st
Square footage: 5000

Address: 128 Cat St.
Square footage: 2000
```

Will structuring the data one way or the other generate higher quality answers?

Example questions: “at what address is the biggest house?”, “at what address is the smallest house?”, “what’s the size of the house at 333 Rodent st?”

Comment: Did you ever end up finding the answer?

Comment: Not yet. I've got some empirical testing to see if it matters. Thanks for pinging me.

Comment: My untested hypothesis is that as long as you can fit each record in a chunk, both will perform the same because the LLM will handle it either way as semantically the same.

Comment: @ajabdelaziz done! Please vote up the question post since you were interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

Structured data in a csv and structured data in a document format performed the same in my tests using ChatGPT3.5. But I had to make an adjustment for optional data features.

**Details**
One interesting case where I had trouble with the document format that didn’t happen with the CSV was due to a feature that was optional:

```
Address: 333 Rodent st
Square footage: 5000
Pool: salt water system

Address: 128 Cat St.
Square footage: 2000
Pool:
```

The empty pool element for 128 Cat St. was coming into my generated text because the LLM would simply use it (sometimes hallucinating a value) because it decided that there was a pool there rather than decide that “Pool:” meant there was no pool there. This didn’t happening with the CSV format probably because delimiters make it clear that there was no data: “,,”. The empty pool issue probably could have been solved with prompting and/or adding “N/A.” But after some thought I realized I shouldn’t put things in the document that didn’t exist. So instead of making my prompt engineering more complicated, during creating the data file, I’ll not have a “Pool:” and so now the data looks like the below:

```
Address: 333 Rodent st
Square footage: 5000
Pool: salt water

Address: 128 Cat St.
Square footage: 2000
```

This resolved the problem with the LLM trying to use the empty pool.

**Conclusion**: use either CSV or structured document. The LLM I used didn’t care. So pick the file format that works best for your data.